# Asp.net link runat server w3c validator

Tags: asp.net, css, html, hyperlink, w3c-validation

when i run a link server side like this:

```
     <link runat="server" id="staticCss" 
href="....css?v=0" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

asp.net renders it with

```
<link runat="server" id="staticCss" 
href="....css?v=0" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ><link>
```

and this fails the w3 validation

> Stray end tag link.

becasuse link tag can't end with **link** but must end with `/`

How can i avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it can’t be avoided. These are the alternatives that you have:

1. Use a static `link` tag without the server processing, if you can
2. Ignore the validation error: browsers handle this markup well and you shouldn’t have any issues on your website
3. Use a .net `literal` to spit out the markup as text: this way you are in total control of the formatting

I have been struggling with .net generated html for a long time, it can be very frustrating. If anyone knows of other ways to solve this I would be very interested to learn.